# simple proof involving representation of exp(x)

Tags: real-analysis, limits, soft-question

Some days ago I presented some exercises to a bunch of engineers. One of the exercises involved was: Use $\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1 + \frac{x}{n}\right)^{n} = e^{x}$ to show that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1 + \frac{\sqrt{n}}{n}\right)^{-n} = 0$. I've done this by showing that $\left(1 + \frac{\sqrt{n}}{n}\right)^{n}$ converges to infinity, using the definition of convergence to show that for each $C >0$, there is an $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that

$$ \left(1 + \frac{\sqrt{n}}{n}\right)^{n} > \left(1 + \frac{C}{n}\right)^{n} \geq e^{C} - 1\quad \forall n \geq N$$

Almost all of them seemed to have trouble understanding the argument. I told them I'd try to find a different angle to the problem, but so far I havent been able to find anything else. Can you think of a more obvious way (perhaps using the famous Sandwich-Lemma) of proving this limit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the Bernoulli inequality, 
$$
\left(1+\frac{\sqrt{n}}{n}\right)^n\ge1+n·\frac{\sqrt{n}}{n}=1+\sqrt{n}
$$

Comment: If the engineers don't get that inequality,tell them it's the first 2 terms of the Binomial expansion. If they don'y get that ,..........

Answer (score 1):

We are looking at the reciprocal of
$$\left(\left(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)^{\sqrt{n}}\right)^{\sqrt{n}}.$$
After a while,
$$\left(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)^{\sqrt{n}}$$
is close to $e$, which is $\gt 2$, so its $\sqrt{n}$-th power is huge.

The definition of convergence may, in this case, and for this audience, interfere with understanding the simple idea involved.